# Can't get sessionStorage to work properly

Tags: javascript, html, session-storage

Essentially there is a parent page which doesn't have any ID. Then, a series of pages with their unique ID's. Once I go back to the parent page I'd like to know the ID from the previous page I was on. I'm only using HTML and JS so I'm restricted to what I can use so I decided to have a go at sessionStorage. At the moment I set up the parameters as:

```
var pgID = $('.wrapper_project').attr('data-id-project');
sessionStorage.setItem("proj", pgID);
var Storage = sessionStorage.getItem("proj");
```

On a page with ID I get the current value from that page

```
console.log(Storage);
```

but when I return to the parent page it comes back as undefined.

I'm not sure if this is the best approach to tackle this issue. Although, sessionStorage seems a pretty good option but I can't get it to work. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to see the data stored in session storage before you exit the page?

Comment: I can see the data related to the page I'm on if it has an ID but when I'm on the parent page (doesn't have an ID and it is not meant to either) it only returns `undefined`. Hope that helps